# Implementation of the "Quantum Verification of Matrix Products" algorithm

Tags: programming, quantum-gate

I would like to implement a Quantum Verification of Matrix Products, using Ambainis OR Burhman algorithm but I don't know how to start. There isn't much documentation about it, and no circuit in the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0409035).

If someone has any advice on how to start it would be pretty helpful.

Comment: Welcome to QCSE! The algorithm is described in figure 1 on page 4 of the paper. Is any part of that description unclear?

Comment: Thanks you :) During lessons, algorithm were impletement with basic circuit. So here, i don't see how to implement it : for example, how do you put the quantum register into superposition with qiskit ? Or the Quantum Walk ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation I wrote a couple of months back: https://github.com/1ntEgr8/qvmp. It uses a QROM to encode the input matrices and vectors, which leads to some saving in number of qubits required.

You can find more details about it here: https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.09914

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).